# Разметка элемента

Tags: html

[Интересующий пример](http://s017.radikal.ru/i402/1112/79/3689603e6b11.png)

В данном элементе есть общий контейнер и два внутри него, один из них "полоса с градиентом", а второй описание, тобишь description. Изначально задана высота в 90пкс, но после добавления большого количества текста див описания растягивается, как сделать что б вместе с ним тянулась и полоса с градиентом ?

Comment: Попробуйте для градиента height: 100%;

Comment: элемент вообще не получает высоты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что самым простым вариантом будет HTML5 и CSS3: например, [так](http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/lineinyi-gradient)

Comment: спешу обрадовать, градиент уже давно есть, а вот высоты резиновой относительно родителя нет

Comment: Здаётся, что @kemerov4anin имел ввиду, что градиент нужно сделать на фон блоку, в котором инфа(который тянется).

Answer (score 0):

нужно что бы градиент был родителем "описания" и с width:auto; а лучше вобще код привести